# Como fazer o link ser clicável, para ser acessado?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print('-----')
print('SITES')
print('-----')

print()
print()




print('Duolingo Brasileiro')
print('Duolingo Inglês')
print('Duolingo Alemão')

escolha_site = str(input('Escolha qual versão do site do duolingo deseja acessar: '))


if escolha_site == 'Duolingo Brasileiro':
print('https://pt.duolingo.com/')

elif escolha_site == 'Duolingo Inglês':
print('https://en.duolingo.com/')

elif escolha_site == 'Duolingo Alemão':
print('https://de.duolingo.com/')
```

O que eu quero fazer é que, quando o usuário desejar acessar tal site, após ele escolher, ele poderia clicar no link, e seria redirecionado para o navegador padrão do PC, no meu caso é o Chrome. Eu não sou um usuário avançado/intermediário de python, mas, já vejo a necessidade de aprender um pouco sobre como mexer na web com python. Lembrando que estes "duolingos", são só para exemplos, eu poderia ter usado outros sites como exemplo. Desculpe por qualquer erro de formatação! Ainda sou novo aqui e tenho muito trabalho para colocar o código, tenho que ficar dando espaços... enfim, não sei mexer muito aqui. Eu usei o "print" só para dar uma interpretada mesmo, porque, não sei com que comando ou módulo irei precisar usar para tornar o link clicável..

Comment: Esse programa está rodando no terminal mesmo?

Comment: Não, estou rodando na própria IDLE do python. Quero fazer que o link seja clicável, lembrando que o PRINT é só um exemplo, não sei qual comando transforma o link em clicável, para rodar no navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BRKappa,

Tente seguir o exemplo abaixo, simplesmente utilizando um link HTML:

```
print('<a href="http://www.exemplo.com.br">Texto do link</a>')
```

Para abrir um link externo no navegador, você deverá utilizar o modulo webbrowser:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://pt.duolingo.com/')
```

É possível utilizar botões e fazer algo assim:

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()

frame = Frame(app)
frame.pack()

url = "https://pt.duolingo.com/"

def OpenUrl():
   webbrowser.open_new(url)

button = Button(frame, text="Duolingo PT", command=lambda aurl=url:OpenUrl(aurl))
button.pack(side = "left", padx = 20, pady = 20)

app.mainloop()
```

---

O modulo webbrowser tem as seguintes funções:

```
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

Exibe a URL usando o browser padrão. Se `new` estiver 0 a URL será aberta na mesma janela do browser se possível. Se `new` estiver 1, uma nova janela do browser será aberta se possível. Se `new` estiver 2, uma nova página (aba) do browser será aberta se possível. Se `autoraise` estiver `True`, a janela será aumentada se possível.

```
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Abre a URL em uma nova janela do navegador padrão, se possível, senão, abre a URL na única janela do navegador.

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Abre a URL em uma nova página (aba) do navegador padrão, se possível, senão
faz o mesmo que o open_new()

```
webbrowser.get([name])
```

Retorna um objeto de controle para o tipo de navegador. Se o nome estiver vazio, devolve um controlador apropriado para um navegador padrão do ambiente.

```
webbrowser.register(name, constructor[, instance])**
```

Registra o nome do tipo de navegador. Uma vez que um tipo de navegador é registrado, a função `get()` pode retornar um controlador para esse tipo de navegador. Se a instância não for fornecida, ou for `None`, o construtor será chamado sem parâmetros para criar uma instância quando necessário. Se a instância for fornecida, o construtor nunca será chamado e pode ser `None`.

Esse ponto de entrada só é útil se você planeja definir a variável BROWSER ou chamar `get()` com um argumento não vazio correspondente ao nome de um manipulador que você declarar.

O módulo webbrowser tem sua documentação no link:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: Eu quero fazer o link ser clicável, resumindo, eu quero que o python mostre o link e que eu possa abrir este link no navegador, entendeu?

Comment: Através do console?

Comment: No próprio IDLE, não no terminal do python(se tiver como, aí eu quero sim).

Comment: Você testou o exemplo da resposta? O que aconteceu?

Comment: Ele só printou aquilo('<a href="https://pt.duolingo.com">Duolingo Brasileiro</a>'), lembrando, eu quero que o link seja clicável, quero poder clicar no link para ir para o navegador...

Comment: @BRKappa ajustei a resposta, verifica se você consegue...

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! Você já sabia disso ou teve que pesquisar??

Comment: Uma coisinha, como eu posso ver os outros comandos que este módulo tem? Quero trabalhar bastante usando web.

Comment: Já havia utilizado esse módulo em projetos de teste, mas tive que pesquisar para relembrar como fazia. Coloquei mais informações sobre o modulo webbrowser.